# Wagtail API - how to exclude fields?

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework, wagtail

In the Wagtail documentation there is a section about removing some fields from the API (http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.2.1/advanced_topics/api/v2/usage.html#removing-all-default-fields) by using URL query part `?fields=_,title`. But this is done from the API consumer perspective. What can I do to exclude some fields on the server side, so no matter what the user types in the URL query part he won't be able to get some fields. I know how to exclude the fields I've added, this is done simply by removing them `api_fields` list. But there are some 'core' fields such as `meta`, `id`. How do I exclude those?

Answer (score 0):

You can register your pages' api endpoint with a custom viewset instead of using the default PageAPIViewSet.

For example, if you want to return only `title` field for your pages:

```
from wagtail.api.v2.views import PagesAPIViewSet, PageSerializer


class MyCustomPagesAPIViewSet(PagesAPIViewSet):
    base_serializer_class = PageSerializer

    body_fields = [
        'title',
    ]

    meta_fields = [
        'parent',
    ]


api_router.register_endpoint('pages', MyCustomPagesAPIViewSet)
```